# ImageView doesn't set itselfs Invisible even if I set it Invisible

Tags: java, android

I am developing an card game and I am trying to set invisible the card once the second player had playied his card.
But even if I have setted the ImageView invisible it doesn't become invisible anyway.
Here's my code:

```
    case HAND_CHECK:
                // give winned cards to the winning player
                giocatoreGiocante =tavoloDaGioco.CalcoloMano();
                if(giocatore1.GetCartaByIndex(0)==null&&giocatore2.GetCartaByIndex(0)==null){
                    gameState =GAME_STATE.CALCOLO_PUNTI;
                }
                else {
                    gameState = GAME_STATE.PESCA;
                }

                //playedCard is an ImageView 

                playedCard.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //this is not execute
                Log.d("PUNTI", "GIOCATORE1="+giocatore1.GetPunti()+"GIOCATORE2="+giocatore2.GetPunti());
                UpdateGame();

                break;
```

playedCard remain visible and I want it to disappear.

Comment: What about `View.GONE` ?

Comment: with View.GONE still remain visible

Comment: The comment is your code is: *playedCard is an ImageView*. Does this mean that playedCard is not the ImageView?

Comment: playedCard is an imageView

Comment: Did you debug the code? Is `playedCard.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` executed? If it is, there is a call after that to `UpdateGame();`. Does this affect the visibility?

Comment: all the code is execute in that block exept that. 
and there isn't setVisibility until new match turn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with View.GONE